# Dynamic Nested Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a problem with my dashboard that uses multiple user access. In the path "/" there is a default and generic dashboard; while in the other dashboard I have the custom users. I use Reactjs and this version of react-router-dom "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2":

```js
<Router basename="/test">
  <Switch>
    <Route  path="/" component={Dashboard} />
    <Route  path="/:username" component={Dashboard} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

In my Dashboard components i have another router:

```js
let { url } = useRouteMatch();

<Switch>
  <Route exact path={`${url}`} component={Library} />  
  <Route path={`${url}/whish`} component={Wishlist} />                  
</Switch>
```

This doesn't work. I have these scenarios:

case A:

/test            Generic Dashboard --> Library  component
/test/whish      Generic Wishlist  --> Wishlist component

case B

/john            John's Dashboard Library
/john/whish       John's Dashboard Wishlist

/Sam             Sam's Dashboard
/Sam/whish        Sam's WhishList

Comment: Can you show us an example in codesandbox or similar? Without seeing your `Dashboard` component, it's difficult to know how this is intended to work.

Comment: @technicallynick https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-galileo-d1ibm

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues in your sandbox.

1. You had missing imports
2. Your `Dashboard` component was using `useRoutMatch` to determine the nested paths. I would recommend checking for the existence of the username and modify your url based on that.
3. Your "La mia Libreria" link was just leading back to "/", which is the base url for the page. You either need to load this content already, or send it to a different url.
4. Your `App.js` had two Routes, one for a username and one without. This fails because, even with a username, your first route catches. You could reorder these so that the username Route is first, but a better solution is to use conditional parameters. You can see my solution in the functional sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-fire-4xklm?file=/src/App.js